# searching for values stored in an arraylist through all the files within a directory and its sub directories

Tags: java, arraylist

I am creating a program in java that searches for a word in all the files in a directory and lists them. I have tried using findWithinhorizon function however it seems that it checks only for one word and cannot accept an arraylist as a parameter. 
This is want I am trying to do:
There is an array list containing values say(word1, word2, word3, word4). I want to search all the files for these words in the directory that i specify and its sub directories and list all the file names along with the path that contain these words.

Example: it takes the first value from the array list i.e. word1 look for the files containing word1 in the directory(and its sub directories) that I specified and list all the files. then it takes the 2nd word from array list word2 searches it in the directory and lists all the files and so on.

any help is appreciated.
thanks.

Comment: Can you show us what you already have (code)?

Comment: Do you want to search for the words in the file's contents or just in the filenames?

Answer (score 0):

List all the files in a directory.

`public void listFilesAndFilesSubDirectories(String directoryName){

```
    File directory = new File(directoryName);

    //get all the files from a directory
    File[] fList = directory.listFiles();

    for (File file : fList){
        if (file.isFile()){
            System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
        } else if (file.isDirectory()){
            listFilesAndFilesSubDirectories(file.getAbsolutePath());
        }
    }
}`
```

Now loop through your list of files reading each one. Now iterate the list containing the words, check with each word. If you find the word, add the file name in another list.

See to that you iterate the file in the outer loop and the word inside the file loop.